# Passing value from one servlet to another won't work with android application

Tags: android, servlets

There are two servlets in my application. The first servlet consists a `post` method and the second one consists a `get` method. The first servlet passes a username to the second servlet. I am using `httpsession` to pass the object. When I call from Postman app on my computer everything works fine, but when I call from android application it shows null object.

Here is my code:
First servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String userName,password;
    userName=request.getParameter("userName").toString();
    password=request.getParameter("password").toString
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("userId",userName);
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/another servlet");
            rd.forward(request,response);
            }
```

Second Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GetUserTran cp = new GetUserTran();
    //cp.setBoId((String)request.getAttribute("boId"));
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String urname = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
    System.out.println(urname);
```

}

Comment: Please post some code with explanations.

Comment: I have added a code

Comment: Post the relevant android code and the LogCat also?